Mermaid Block Diagram: Spanning Multiple Columns Within Group
I have the following Mermaid block diagram:
block-beta
    columns 4
    a:1
    block:b:3
        columns 3
        c:1
        d:1
        e:1
        f:3
    end
    g:4
    h:4
    style f stroke-width:5px

Which renders as follows:

However, I'd like f to span over the entire width of c, d, and e combined.
How can I achieve this? Ideally, f would be optically outside the group of c, d, and e.
EDIT: I found the relevant code

I suspect this is a bug in block-beta and suggest that you raise an issue on GitHub.
When you omit the :3 from block:b:3, the :3 in f:3 is honored, but then block g goes into the first row, because block b takes up only one column (although it is rendered wider than block a).
The best I could achieve is the following. It makes block b only one column wide and compensates for that by two additional spaces in the first row.


<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs"></script>
<pre class="mermaid">
block-beta
    columns 4
    a:1
    block:b
      columns 3
      c d e f:3
    end
    space:2
    g:4
    h:4
</pre>




Thanks; unfortunately, this makes the diagram extremely small in my specific embedded setting.
